# Can't populate a jcombo box when using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

I have used this statements to populate jcombobox from MySql database table using Hibernate

```
    String SQL_QUERY ="from Item items";
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
        for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
        Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
        jcbItemCode.addItem(row[0]);
        }
```

Here Item is my class name & items is my database table name. But NetBeans gives an error like follows & jcombo box does not populate.

```
INFO: schema update complete
Hibernate: select item0_.itemid as col_0_0_ from items item0_
eretailer.Item$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$99948c46 cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

How can I correct this problem. I have searched but couldn't find suitable answer. 
I have used this method before...

```
String SQL_QUERY = "Select items.iid,items.idiscription,items.iprice from Item items";
          org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
          for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
          Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
          jcbItemCode.addItem(row[0]);
          }
```

This is working perfectly.

Perhaps Net beans does not allow that way. I want to know what exactly this is. Hope your help.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks! & How can I populate combo box..

Comment: What line of code causes your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query `from Item items`, as indicated by the error message, doesn't return `Object[]` instances. It returns `Item` instances.

If you want your combo box to contain Item instances, just use

```
for(Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
    Item item = (Item) it.next();
    jcbItemCode.addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but this gives another error like this
Mar 09, 2012 11:46:28 PM org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException <init>
SEVERE: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
 at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:57)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:111)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.invoke(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:150)
 at eretailer.Item$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a44e
...

Comment: This is a different problem. You're probably accessing an uninitialized lazy association somewhere in your code. Make sure that all the needed associations are initialized, and if you don't understand, ask another question, with the whole stack trace.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. First of all, your query is not a SQL query, but a HQL query. The working query loads fields of the Item entity. The other one loads instances of the Item entity. And if you want to add the ID of the entity in your combo, then use `jcbItemCode.addItem(item.getId());`

Comment: @ JB Nizet, thanks in advance... jcbItemCode.addItem(item.getId()); is working.. :)